# How to upload specific folders with login system in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, file-upload, authentication

I will create an `ASP.NET` Web Application like this;

1. Users can login their own `username` and `password`.
2. Users can file `upload` their own folder (I define the folders manually), and also they can see all files in their own page and they can download them.

I think I can use an architecture like this;

1. I should use [`ASP.NET Login Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx), we all agree with that. But I also should use C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regsql.exe and [`ASP.NET Web site Administration Tool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0.aspx)? What does exactly `aspnet_regsql.exe` do? What does `Administration Tool` do? They are (Login controls + aspnet_regsql.exe + Administration Tool) only I need for creating a user login system?
2. For file upload I think to use [`File Upload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx) control. Then, For example; if I have a user "A", folder should be like `http://ourserver/A`. I have no idea how can I upload file to specific folder. And how can I show to users their own uploaded files? (Also users should download them) Is there any `asp.net` control for doing this ?

**EDIT**: I prefer step by step explanation rather than giving some code. I want to also understand what these applications are doing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) If you run the regsql tool, it will popup a screen asking for some sql information and then create a set of tables relative to membership etc. If you start a basic MVC 3 application, it comes with an account controller, login, logout, forgot password all wired up. This talks to that database. Your alternative is to create a custom membership provider, there are lots of tutorials out there for doing that. You can control more things with the custom membership provider, but it's a bit more work.

2) AmRans example code is perfect for saving the actual file. As far as the folder for the given user goes, then I would probably configure a base directory in your web.config, then;

```
if( Directory.Create( Path.Combine( baseDirectory, UserDirectory)).Exists) {

}
```

although if you're using .NET 2, then that might remain;

```
string savePath = Path.Combine( baseDirectory, UserDirectory);

Directory.Create( savePath );

if( Directory.Exists( savePath)) {
}
```

For viewing of those files, if the user is logged in, you can query the save directory + username and list out all the files in that.

Comment: So, for the login system, i need only regsql + asp.net login control right ? What i want the system is easy, people can login, they download and upload their spesific folder. That's it.

Comment: Yeah, I remember seeing that if you create a new Website it comes with the authentication stuff and if you've got the connection string configured, on first run it will run the script in the background for you. You might not actually need to run the tool. The out of the box membership provider sounds like it might be the best way of getting you started though.

Comment: So basicly, first I run aspnet_regsql.exe, then it will create some table in my database, then i put login controls to database and then ? Can you give me an example using aspnet_regsql.exe in there ??

Comment: More simple @Soner Gönül
a) Create a new MVC site
b) On first debug run the own asp.net service creates the tables
c) The default website has a login view and creates account view, modifing the LoginController you'll can add the logic for create folder at create account action.

Answer (score 1):

See the code below , not the exact but might be help for you. Here UploadTypes is a custom enum and userId is the current user logged in , id (primary key of the table or any thing that is unique), with control name, passed from Front end.

```
  /// <summary>
        /// returns the virtual application path of uploaded file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fu"></param>
        /// <param name="uploadType"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetAppFileUploadPath(FileUpload fu, UploadTypes uploadType, int userId)
        {
           var path =  string.Format("~/Images/no.gif"); 

            if (fu.HasFile)
            {
                if (fu.FileContent.Length > 0)
                {
                    var filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fu.PostedFile.FileName);
                    var extension = Path.GetExtension(fu.PostedFile.FileName);
                    switch (uploadType)
                    {
                        case UploadTypes.Images:
                            _validExtensions = new List<string> 
                                                {
                                                    ".bmp", ".jpg",".jpeg",".gif",".png" 
                                                };

                            if (_validExtensions.Contains(extension.ToLower()))
                            {
                                var newFileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}{3}", filename, userId, Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 5), extension);
                                var serverUploadPath = string.Format("{0}/VirtualOffice/Uploads/ProductImage/{1}", HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, newFileName);
                                path = string.Format("~/VirtualOffice/Uploads/ProductImage/{0}", newFileName);
                                fu.SaveAs(serverUploadPath);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Common.ShowMessage("Only image files allowed, bmp, jpg , gif or png.");
                            }
                            break;
                        case UploadTypes.Documents:
                            _validExtensions = new List<string> 
                                                {
                                                    ".doc", ".rtf",".docx",".pdf",".txt" 
                                                };
                            if (_validExtensions.Contains(extension.ToLower()))
                            {
                                var newFileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}{3}", filename, userId, Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 5), extension);
                                var serverUploadPath = string.Format("{0}/VirtualOffice/Uploads/ProductImage/{1}", HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, newFileName);
                                fu.SaveAs(serverUploadPath);
                                path = string.Format("~/VirtualOffice/Uploads/ProductImage/{0}", newFileName);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Common.ShowMessage("Only valid text files allowed, doc, docx ,rtf, pdf or txt.");

                            }
                            break;
                    }

                }
            }

            return path;

        }
```

This is my custom file upload code to allow either image or document as per scenario.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, before jumping on to what controls to use, whether to create a `Website` project or ASP.Net MVC3 application, I think its crucial to understand what your core design should be. Implementing the GUI aspect of login is easy, what is important is the backend piece of it.

How do you authenticate users? What role should they have (read only, write only, read/write etc). What mode should you choose and how do you configure your site to accept one of these forms of authentication. If you have an understanding of these, you can skip this, otherwise I would suggest reading up here: [ASP.NET authentication and authorization](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPDOTNETauthentication.aspx) and this: [ASP.NET 2.0 Membership, Roles, Forms Authentication, and Security Resources](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx)

Now the file upload and management part - well, while its fun to do things on your own from a learning perspective, I also believe in not reinventing the wheel (if it suits your purpose of course). There are good open source projects that you can benefit from like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WebFileManager.aspx  (created by Jeff Atwood and has a good explanantion)

http://www.filemanager.3ntar.net/

http://www.ajaxfilebrowser.com/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In File upload you can check user after login than check the folder is exist or not by using:

```
Directory.Exist("FolderPath")
```

If it is exist upload to that folder other wise you can create folder using

```
Directory.Create("Folder Path and Name");
```

Then upload file to that folder

Answer (score 0):

Note that because of security purpose, you might have to provides writting rights to `NETWORK SERVICE` on you server for each folder you want to upload in. Because of that, I'll recommand you to create a folder in your root directory or anywhere you want and provide write access to this folder, say FolderA. So, any child folder will have same rights.

Also, there's plenty controls that can handle files from the web. Unfortunaly, most of them cost something (if you want one stable and who's working great). One we bought and work great for us, is [this one (CuteWebUI.AjaxUploader)](http://ajaxuploader.com/). It allows you to specify many file at once or not, use Flash, IFrame or AJAX as you want it, save temporaly file automaticaly, etc.

Good luck!

Note : I talk french, so sorry for my english